# Proportional resize of the dynamically loaded images and centering them vertically and horizontally

Tags: jquery, css, image-resizing, centering

I have a few dynamically loaded images, with width and height being set inside the code. Obviously it doesn't scale them proportionally. This is the code I use to **load the images dynamically**:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command:"top3"}, function(result) {
        for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++) {
            $("<div id='top3imgContainer'><a href='images/" + result[i].imageFileName + "' rel='shadowbox[top3]' title='" 
                + result[i].imageHeader + "'><img width='220' height='220' src='images/" + result[i].imageFileName + "' id='top3img' /></a></div>").appendTo("#divTop3");
        } Shadowbox.init({
                continuous:true,
                displayCounter:false,
                overlayColor:"#a09e92",
                overlayOpacity:0.8
            });
     });
});
```

**The HTML**:

```
<div id="divContent">
    <div id="divTop3">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is **the CSS**:

```
#divContent {
width:860px;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #dbd9ca;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
margin:5px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:5px;
clear:both;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#divTop3 {
width:850;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}

#top3imgContainer {
width:245px;
height:270px;
background-image:url(../images_ui/frame.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

img#top3img {
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
margin-left:13px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-top:17px;
}
```

And after applying the CSS this is how it looks:
http://i44.tinypic.com/168x7i9.jpg

Not exactly proportional and not really centered.
So the question is - how can I scale them proportionally? And after that - how can I center each image in its div?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/ydZJk/

The main changes are these:

```
#top3imgContainer {
    width:       100px;
    height:      120px;
    line-height: 120px;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width:  100px; /* check in all browsers! */
    max-height: 120px; /* Old IEs won't like it */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply! Yep, that pretty much did the trick! And I thought I'm gonna need a lot of JS to resize the images proportionally... Again, thank you! PS. I'm still not allowed to vote up answers... Sorry! :(

Comment: Happy to help :) You don't have to upvote the answer, just click the empty tick under the up/downwote arrows. And really check the solution in every browser you can, because some of them (hopefully only the older one) just stretched the image to the max-width/height.

Comment: Got it, ticked it! :) And thanks again, also for the browsers compatibility suggestion! Will look into it!